# Why can't I enter the data into the database even though the codes are correct and no error appear?

Tags: php, sql

There is no change and no response in the form or in the database. I believe
the code is okay as no error appears and I included the connect database pdo. The connection is okay, and I changed the position of code to be above the form and under form but still no response. I connected correctly.
I separated the php page but it did not help.

Where is the problem in this code ?
Summary of the problem:
1-no response or error message
2- data not inserted into database

```
  connection database:

  <?php
  $dsn ='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=person';
  $user ='root';
  $pass = "";
  $option = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8",);

  try{
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn,  $user , $pass, $option);

  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);}
  catch(PDOException $e){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());   }


    and form of html:

    <div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=" POST">


    <label for="fname"> الاسم </label><br>
    <input type=" text" id="fname" name="username" placeholder=" الاسم"><br>


    <label for="email"> البريد الالكتروني </label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني "><br>

    <label for="valley"> اسم الحي </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="valley" name="valley" placeholder="اسم الحي "><br>
    <label for="phone"> رقم الجوال</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="رقم الجوال  "><br>
    <label for="subject">الطلب</label><br>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subj" placeholder="اكتب الطلب " style="height:200px"> 
    </textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ارسل">

    </form>
    </div>
    <br>


         
   php and query  insertion to database 
 <?php

 include('connect_pdo.php');

 if (isset($_post['submit'])) {
 $name = $_POST['username'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $valley = $_POST['valley'];
 $phone = $_POST['mobile'];
 $subject = $_POST['subj'];


 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (username,email,valley,mobile,subj)
VALUES('$name','$email','$valley','$phone' ,'$subject')");




 if ($stmt->execute()) {
 echo "تم الارسال بنجاح";} 
 else {

 echo "تم الارسال"   }  }
```

Comment: Change $_post['submit'] to $_POST['submit']

Comment: no change@Rinshan Kolayil

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but have you tried removing the space from `method=" POST"`?

Comment: Do you have both PHP and MySQL error reporting turned on?

Comment: Also, while developing, avoid `try`. You want to see those errors at this stage.

Comment: also no any change @ Rinshan Kolayil

Comment: change method=" POST" to method="POST"

Comment: Yes it exists@Chris Haas

Comment: no change and no error also@ Chris Haas

Comment: i find it now , remove try and then back it again like  chris said @Chris Haas